# VBA Access Arguments Passing Values

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

Access 2013

I'm calling a formula to modify a string and it's changing the values w/in the parent sub.

Example:

```
Debug.Print Str 'Hello World my name is bob
BOBexists = InStringChceck(Str,"bob")
Debug.Print Str 'HELLO WORLD MY NAME IS BOB
Debug.Print BOBexists 'TRUE
```

I've used this function, InStringCheck, in Excel VBA before (and it's just an example, all of my string tools are doing this same thing now and I don't know why)

```
Function InStringCheck(Phrase as string, Term as string) as Boolean
    Phrase = UCase(Phrase)
    Term = UCase(Term)
    if instr(1, Phrase, Term) then InStringCheck = True else InStringCheck = False
end function
```

In several of my functions I manipulate the input variables, to arrive at a solution, but I don't want those manipulations to persist outside of the function unless I pass them back up - some how they're being passed up, but they're ***not dimed as public variables***

Comment: use the ByVal keyword in the parameters declarations InStringCheck(ByVal Phrase as string, ByVal Term as string)

Comment: As an aside, you can change `if instr(1, Phrase, Term) then InStringCheck = True else InStringCheck = False` to `InStringCheck = InStr(1, Phrase, Term)`. Never return `True` or `False` based on a Boolean condition. It's already `True` or `False` by definition. Just return the Boolean condition itself. You don't have to interrogate it and return another Boolean.

Comment: Other side note: Unless you specify `vbBinaryCompare` in the call or in `Option Compare`, `InStr()` is case-insensitive. So `UCase` isn't needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA parameters are implicitly passed by reference (`ByRef`). This means you're passing a *reference* to the value, not the value itself: mutating that value inside the procedure will result in that mutated value being visible to the calling code.

This is often used as a trick to return multiple values from a function/procedure:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal inValue1 As Integer, ByRef outResult1 As Integer, ...)
```

You have two options:

- Pass the parameters by value (`ByVal`)
- Introduce local variables and mutate them instead of mutating the paramters (and heck, pass the parameters `ByRef` explicitly)

---

If you have lots of occurrences of parameters being implicitly passed `ByRef` in your project, fixing them everywhere can easily get tedious. With [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) you can easily locate all occurrences, navigate there, and apply appropriate fixes:

[image: Rubberduck inspection results]

> Disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in the Rubberduck project.

Answer (score 2):

Building a little on @Sorcer's answer, VBA has default Sub/Functions parameters passing "by reference" (i. e.: "ByRef" keyword assumed if not specified) so that if you don't want their "inside" modifications survive outside them you have to explicitly type "ByVal" keyword before them in the arguments list.

But you have the option to avoid such modifications take place altoghether by using `StrComp()`:

```
Function InStringCheck(Phrase as string, Term as string) as Boolean
    InStringCheck = StrComp(Phrase, Term, vbTextCompare) = 0
End Function
```

Which could also lead you to avoid the use of  `InStringCheck()` in favour of a *direct* use of `StrComp()` in your code